# Not able to fetch the record from salesforce history using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, record, getter

I am new to LWC. I have this picklist field in the custom object. So this is the apex method that is exposed to lwc.

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getPriorStatus(String recordId) {
        List<TestApex__History > hist;
        String previousValue = '';
        try {
            hist = Database.query('SELECT Id, Field, DataType, OldValue, NewValue, ParentId FROM TestApex__History Where ParentId =: recordId AND Field = \'FavPicklist__c\' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1');

            previousValue = String.valueOf(hist[0].OldValue);

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return previousValue ;
    }
}
```

Inside my lwc, I wire this apex method so I can get the string value of the apex method it return.

```
    import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
    import { getRecord, getFieldValue, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import getPriorStatus from '@salesforce/apex/ApexA.getPriorStatus';
    
    @api recordId;
    previousStatus;
    
 fields = ['CustomObj.FavPicklist__c', 'CustomObj.RecordType.DeveloperName'];

    methodA(currentStatus){
            getPriorStatus({ recordId: '$recordId' })
            .then(response => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    
    
            if(this.previousStatus !== currentStatus) {
                // call another method
            }
   }
```

This is the error I encountered:
[image]

I want to check if picklist was changed using lwc. However, I'm getting an error fetching the salesforce data using lwc. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I came with another solution by creating a new field and it updates via trigger to get the old value of the picklist.

```
  fields = ['CustomObj.FavPicklist__c', 'CustomObj.RecordType.DeveloperName', 'CustomObj.FavPicklistOldValue__c'];
```

The problem I have now is my lwc is looping endlessly

```
 methodA(currentStatus){
       let hasCalled = false; // this is always false upon running?

       alert('is it equal? ' + JSON.stringify(oldStatus !== currentStatus));
       alert('hasCalled ' + JSON.stringify(hasCalled));

        if(currentStatus !== oldStatus && !hasCalled) {
            hasCalled= true; // it does not update
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing anything else in method or just only doing a single soql query? This error comes if you try to do even a single dml in cacheable=true method.

Comment: are you referring to getPriorStatus method?

Comment: No, that is all the code inside the getPriorStatus method

Comment: Are you calling any other apex method from js at same time?

Comment: yes, I have another import there inside the lwc but there is no soql query in that method

Comment: does that method have a dml? Add apex and js code of that method also

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post since I come with another solution. But my lwc is looping endlessly

Comment: don't do these changes by adding a new field to keep history records. Just remove cacheable=true from the apex method, and it will work.